# Why SQLPLUS not allowing to execute a query which longer than 256 characters via PuTTY?

Tags: sqlplus

I tried as below:

```
sqlplus username/passwd@dbname
```

Here it is connected
But in the `sqlplus` prompt whenever I try to execute/write a query which is longer than 256 chars, the prompt isn't allowing. it is omitting the chars after 256 chars.

Comment: can u upload snap of that error...

Comment: There is no Error: If I paste the query (or any string) it is taking only first 256 chars only

Comment: In sqlplus prompt whenever I type a query which is more than the length of 256 chars, see the below
SQL> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
for example the above after 256 a's I'm not able to type anything more in the same line